# how to fix this Javascript Image Slideshow Error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I tried to make an image slideshow on javascript but when I run it the first image doesn't show up until I hit the dot or previous and next button. It doesn't show any error too but the image just doesn't show up for the first time. This code consists of Javascript, HTML, and CSS. I need to finish this by tomorrow so anyone that can help me with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function next(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function dot(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slide{
        max-width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }

    .picture{
        display: none;
    }

    .prev, .next{
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: -22px;
        padding: 16px;
        color: grey;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .next{
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover{
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 40%;
    }

    .text{
        color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background: grey;
        transition: .5 ease;
    }

    .picture:hover .text{
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dot{
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: gray;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover{
        background-color: silver;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="picture" style="">
            <img name="pic0" src="coding.png" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="text">Holy Trinity of Client Side</div>
        </div>

        <div class="picture" style="">
            <img name="pic1" src="html.png" style="width: 400px">
            <div class="text">HTML is the standard markup language for creating Web pages</div>
        </div>

        <div class="picture" align="center">
            <img name="pic2" src="css.png" style="width: 300px">
            <div class="text">CSS are used to format the layout of Web pages</div>
        </div>

        <div class="picture" align="right" style="">
            <img name="pic3" src="js.png" style="width: 300px">
            <div class="text">JavaScript is a programming language that allows you to implement complex features on web pages</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="next(-1)">&#10096;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="next(+1)">&#10097;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="dot(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="dot(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="dot(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="dot(4)"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: I see it correctly! what am I missing here? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/5aj3gvLf/3/

Comment: Just transfer all your js code after the body tag

Comment: just fixed it thank you so much I didn't realize that